# Sheaves of Principal parts

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In EGA IV, Sec. 16, Grothendieck defines the sheaf of principal parts as follows: Let $f:X\rightarrow S$ be a morphism of schemes and $\Delta:X\rightarrow X\times_S X$ the diagonal morphism associated to $f$. $\Delta$ is an immersion, so the corresponding morphism $\Delta^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X\times_S X}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X$ is surjective. Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote its kernel and define the sheaves of principal parts as

$$\mathcal{P}_{X/S}^n:=\Delta^{-1}( \mathcal{O}_{X\times_S X}) / \mathcal{I}^{n+1}$$

In their book on Crystalline cohomology, Berthelot and Ogus define the sheaf of principal parts $\mathcal{P}^n_{X/S}$ as

$$(\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S}\mathcal{O}_X)/\mathbf{I}^{n+1},$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the kernel of the multiplication map from the tensor product to $\mathcal{O}_X$.

My question is probably simple, but I don't know how to see it:
Why are those definitions equivalent if $X$ and $S$ are not affine and $n>0$?

I've not seen the second definition anywhere else, although it seems somewhat nicer than the first one...

Comment: I fixed an error in the statement.  I looked it up to make sure.  

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement holds in general if $f : X \to S$ is a morphism of locally ringed spaces. The fibred product of locally ringed spaces can be constructed explicitly without gluing constructions, and also restricts to the fibred product of schemes. See [this article](http://maddin.110mb.com/pdf/faserprodukte.pdf) (german; shall I translate it?) for details. I will make use of the explicit description given there. Also I use stalks all over the place. Probably this is not the most elegant proof, but it works.

First we construct a homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X \to \Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X}$. For that we compute the stalks at some point $x \in X$ lying over $s \in S$:

$(\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X)_x = \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x},$

$(\Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X})_x = \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X,\Delta(x)} = (\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x})_{\mathfrak{q}}$,

where $\mathfrak{q}$ is the kernel of the canonical homomorphism

$\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \kappa(x), a \otimes b \mapsto \overline{ab}.$

Thus we get, at least, homomorphisms between the stalks (namely localizations). In order to get sheaf homomorphisms out of them, the following easy lemma is useful:

(*) Let $F,G$ be sheaves on a topological space $X$ and for every $x \in X$ let $s_x : F_x \to G_x$ be a homomorphism. Suppose that they fit together in the sense that for every open $U$, every section $f \in F(U)$ and every $x \in U$ there is some open neighborhood $x \in W \subseteq U$ and some section $g \in G(W)$ such that $s_y$ maps $f_y$ to $g_y$ for all $y \in W$. Then there is a sheaf homomorphism $s : F \to G$ inducing $s$.

This can be applied in the above situation: Every section in a neighborhood of $x$ in $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X$ induced by an element in $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_S(V)} \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for some neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $s$ such that $U \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$. This yields a section in $\mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X}$ on the basic-open subset $\Omega(U,U,V;1)=U \times_V U$ and thus a section of $\Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X}$ on $U$. It is easily seen, that this construction yields the natural map on the stalks.

Thus we have a homomorphism $\alpha : \mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X \to \Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X}$. Now let $J$ be the kernel of the multiplication map $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X$ and $I$ be the kernel of the homomorphism $\Delta^\# : \Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X} \to \mathcal{O}_X$. Then for every $n \geq 1$ our $\alpha$ restricts to a homomorphism

$(\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X)/J^n \to (\Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X})/I^n,$

which is given at $x \in X$ by the natural map

$(\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}) / \mathfrak{p}^n \to ((\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}) / \mathfrak{p}^n)_{\mathfrak{q}}$,

where $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq \mathfrak{q}$ is the kernel of the multiplication map $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

We want to show that this map is an isomorphism, i.e. that the localization at $\mathfrak{q}$ is not needed. For that it is enough to show that every element in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, whose image in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is invertible, is invertible modulo $\mathfrak{p}^n$. Or in other words: Preimages of units are units with respect to the projection

$(\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}) / \mathfrak{p}^n \to (\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}) / \mathfrak{p}^1  \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

However, this follows from the observation that the kernel $\mathfrak{p}^1 / \mathfrak{p}^n$ is nilpotent; cf. also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31495/when-does-a-ring-surjection-imply-a-surjection-of-the-group-of-units/32919#32919).

I'm sure that there is also a proof which avoids stalks at all.

EDIT: So here is a direct construction of the homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X \to \Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X}$:

Let $p_1,p_2$ be the projections $X \times_S X \to X$. Then we have for $i=1,2$ the homomorphism

$\mathcal{O}_X \to {p_i}_* \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X} \to {p_i}_* \Delta_* \Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X} = (p_i \Delta)_* \Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X} = \Delta^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X}$,

and they commute over $f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S$. Thus we get the desired homomorphism. But I think stalks are convenient when we want to show that this is an isomorphism when modding out the ideals.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks, I forgot about this question. If I remember correctly, I came to the same conclusion as you, but I constructed the global map differently: Let $p_1,p_2$ denote the projections $X\times_S X\rightarrow X$, then $p_i\Delta=id$, for both $i$. So if we pull back the morphisms of sheaves $p_i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X\times X}$ via $\Delta$, we obtain two $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S)$-linear morphisms $\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow\Delta^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X\times X}$. This should give the same morphism as your construction.

Comment: Oops, apparently you edited and I commented simultaneously. 

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg Ok, I suggest to translate the paper. I'd be interested.

Comment: I had already completed it, but then realized that W. D. Gillam has already done something similar: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.2139.pdf