# Reference for the fact that $SL_n(O_K)$ surjects onto $SL_n(O_K/I)$ for any ideal I

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-groups

Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers in an algebraic number field $K$ and let $I \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ be a nonzero proper ideal.  It is not hard to see that the map $\text{SL}_n(\mathcal{O}_K) \rightarrow \text{SL}_n(\mathcal{O}_K/I)$ is surjective.  For instance, $\mathcal{O}_K/I$ is a product of local rings, and over such rings the special linear group is generated by elementary matrices.  I need this theorem in a paper I am writing, and I'd rather not spend a paragraph proving it.  Does anyone know a good reference?

Comment: Why not giving the same argument as you gave us (while saying at the same time that the result is well-known)? After all it just takes one line: any reference will take more, and would require infinitely more work for the reader.

Comment: btw the argument works with no change with an arbitrary noetherian domain of Krull dimension 1.

Comment: in addition there is no need to invoke local rings and product decomposition, but just semilocal, which is the classical assumption in K-theory texts.

Answer (score 5):

[Platonov-Rapinchuk](http://books.google.com/books/about/Algebraic_Groups_and_Number_Theory.html?id=NpVdWdFq5YMC) is the canonical reference.

**EDIT** A less nuclear option (and one I should have mentioned in the first place is [Morris Newman's Integral Matrices.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w61gpdhx88dq1ur/%5BMorris_Newman%5D_Integral_matrices.pdf) I think chapter 7 and/or 9 have a(n elementary) proof.

Comment: Can you tell me where in this ~650 page book the result can be found?  I quickly skimmed though it and didn't find it.

Comment: Chapter 7. What you are looking for is "strong approximation", essentially.

Comment: I suppose I could cite strong approximation, though that is sort of killing an ant with a nuclear weapon.  I'll accept this answer if no one provides a source for a more elementary argument (e.g. like the one I sketched in my question).

Comment: I took a look through Newman's book, and the only relevant result is Theorem VII.6.  At first glance, this looks like what I want; however, if you read a little further back you'll see that he is only considering PID's, and moreover, he just asserts without proof that the reduction map is surjective (which I guess is obvious for PID's).