# Criterion for Ramification of ray class field $K(\mathfrak{p})$ in $\mathfrak{p}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

The context: We consider ideal theoretic formulation of global class field theory of a number field $K$ and in following all used terminology I'm going to use is adapted from these notes: https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2017fa/LectureNotes22.pdf.

Let $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{p}$ a prime modulus, and we want to consider the ramification bahavior of the ray class field $K(\mathfrak{m})/K$ at  $\mathfrak{p}$.
Important note on notations: Usually in must literature on this topic the ray class field with modulus $\mathfrak{m}$ is denoted by $K^{\mathfrak{m}}$, but in the linked notes the notion "$K^{\mathfrak{m}}$" is reserved for certain subgroup of $K^{\times}$, this might cause confusions. I would like to follow notion from the script, see also below.

In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/466101) is claimed that there is a criterion on ramification behavior of  $K(\mathfrak{m})/K$ at  $\mathfrak{p}$ depending on the surjectivity of the map $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times} \to (\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})^{\times}$ induced from canonical projection of the integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ wrt $\mathfrak{m}$.
More precisely, the claim in the linked answer states that:

> If the unit group $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_K$ surjects onto the unit of residue field $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})^{\times}$ then the ray class field of $K(\mathfrak{m})$ is unramified at $\mathfrak{m}$, and so has conductor $1$ not conductor $\mathfrak{m}$. If the image of the unit group is not surjective, then $K(\mathfrak{m})$ has conductor $\mathfrak{m}$.

Could somebody elaborate why this equivalence holds? I not see how this can be deduced using methods presented in the linked script above.

The objects enumerated at the first page - especially the crucially involved groups  $K^{1, \mathfrak{m}} \subset K^{\mathfrak{m}} \subset K^{\times}$ in the construction of ray class group with modulus $\mathfrak{m}$ - seemingly not captures (through the eyes of the posed inequalities in terms of valuations) the information if a unit $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}^{\times}_K$ generates the group  $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})^{\times} \cong \mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$, for certain prime power $q$.

By definition of ray class field $K(\mathfrak{m})/K$, it's congruence subgroup equals $\mathcal{R}^{\mathfrak{m}}_K$, so in light of Definition 22.3. and Proposition 22.4. $K(\mathfrak{m})$ is unramified in $\mathfrak{m}$ if there exist an itermediate group $\mathcal{R}^{(1)}_K \subset C \subset \mathcal{I}^{(1)}_K $ with $\mathcal{R}^{\mathfrak{m}}_K \cap \mathcal{I}^{(1)}_K = C \cap \mathcal{I}^{\mathfrak{m}}_K$.

**Problem:** But I not see how this depends on if the unit group $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_K$ surject onto $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})^{\times}$.
The main problem I see so far is as I wrote before  that the definition of $K^{1, \mathfrak{m}} $ expressed in terms of certain inequalities with respect valuations, not captures the information if a unit $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}^{\times}_K$ generates the group  $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})^{\times}$.

Say, $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}^{\times}_K$, what could be it's image in $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})^{\times}$? The latter is a cyclic group.

Clearly, the valuation $v_{\mathfrak{p}}$ can detect if $\alpha$ is of the shape $1+ t, t \in \mathfrak{p}$. But what if $\alpha$ is mapped **not** to $1$? If i'm not missing something, then the posed valuative inequality cannot detect if $\alpha$ is mapped to a generator or a different non trivial element of $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})^{\times}$.

So I not understand how to see that the quoted answer above gives a criterion for ramification of ray class field $K(\mathfrak{p})$ in $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Why are you writing " surjectivity of the canonical map $\mathcal O_K^\times \to (\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m)^\times$ restricted to the unit group $U_K \subset \mathcal O_K^\times$" and "the units $U_K$ of $\mathcal O_K^\times$" when $\mathcal O_K^\times$ is notation for the unit group of $\mathcal O_K$?  Don't mix up the ring $\mathcal O_K$ with its unit group $\mathcal O_K^\times$.

Comment: @KConrad: I assumed that $\mathcal O_K^\times$ is notion reserved for $\mathcal O_K-\{0\}$. If  $\mathcal O_K^\times$ is standard notion for unit group instead (what I denoted above by $U_K$), I will correct it, sorry for causing confusions.

Comment: When $R$ is a commutative ring $R^\times$ is the units in $R$: elements in $R$ that are a group under multiplication. So if $R$ is a field, $R^\times = R-\{0\}$, but otherwise $R^\times$ is smaller than $R-\{0\}$. I see no need to have notation for the nonzero elements, e.g., you can write about "surjectivity of the canonical map $\mathcal O_K\to\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m$ restricted to the unit group". There's no sensible map from nonzero elements of $\mathcal O_K$ to nonzero elements of $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m$: many nonzero elements in $\mathcal O_K$ reduce to $0\bmod\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Your edited post refers to the “canonical map $\mathcal O_K\to(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m)^\times$”, which is incorrect: the target should be $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m$. Please correct all typographical errors.  Elsewhere, there is no need to use parentheses in $(\mathcal O_K)^\times$. It is standard to write $\mathcal O_K^\times$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the global units surject, then any generator of a principal ideal coprime to ${\mathfrak{m}}$ can always be multiplied by a unit to replace it with a generator of the same principal ideal that is congruent to $1$ modulo ${\mathfrak{m}}$. In other words, all principal ideals are already in "the ray". It follows that in this case, the ray class group is just the usual ideal class group (because the whole group of principal ideals is divided out), and the ray class field you get is just the Hilbert class field of $K$, which is unramified over $K$ (and which is $K$ itself when $K$ has class number $1$).

When the units don't surject, this isn't always possible - there'll be principal ideals generated by elements coprime to ${\mathfrak{m}}$ that *cannot* be sent into the $1$ mod ${\mathfrak{m}}$ residue class by multiplying them with a global unit. The ray class group will be larger than the class group (because now a proper subgroup of the group of principal ideals is divided out), the ray class field will be larger than the Hilbert class field, and it will have to be ramified because the Hilbert class field is the maximal unramified abelian extension.

I strongly recommend working out some examples by hand, starting from a quadratic or cubic base field $K$. (And I mean *by hand* - it doesn't even require a pocket calculator.)

---

Actually the simplest examples start from $K=\mathbb{Q}$ with global units $\{\pm 1\}$. Modulo $\mathfrak{m}=(2)$, the global units surject; the ray class field is $\mathbb{Q}$ itself - there is no number field with discriminant $2$. Same modulo $(3)$. But modulo $(5)$ you get a nontrivial ray class fields, since the global units no longer surject - namely $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Passing to prime-power moduli, mod $(4)$ you still get back $\mathbb{Q}$ itself, but mod $(8)$ the global units no longer surject: you get $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as the ray class field.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This also gives a "geometric insight" why in order to extend the notion of class group to ramified situation, it is intuitively reasonable to keep on the the philosophy that "the thing" $\mathcal{R}_K^{\mathcal{m}}$ which we want to mod out, should be still given as bunch of certain rays.

Comment: One point I still not completely understand. Your argument as far I understand you correctly shows that if we have this surjection of units, then in terms of the notion at first page in linked notes, the imposed inequalities defining $K^{1, \mathfrak{m}}$ not give additional restrictions on $\mathcal{R}^{\mathfrak{m}}_K$, so $Cl_K^{\mathfrak{m}}$ is $\mathcal{I}^{\mathfrak{m}}_K$ modulo **all** all principal ideals. Comparing it with the usual ideal class group given as quotient of group of all fractional ideals modulo principal ideals,

Comment: to which it should be isomorphic according to your claim, what about the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{m}$ itself and elements in the group which have it as non trivial factor. It it's not principal, then it's class naturally is contained in the usual ideal class group, but by definition of $\mathcal{I}^{\mathfrak{m}}_K$ it would be then missing in the quotent $Cl_K^{\mathfrak{m}}$, therefore, why we can conclude that $Cl_K^{\mathfrak{m}}$ is iso to usual ideal class group? Key problem: What happens with class of $\mathfrak{p}$ in the quotient group?

Comment: Good point! Ideals that aren't coprime to the modulus are excluded from consideration, so yes, if we're being precise we have to deal with a subgroup of fractional ideals coprime to $\mathfrak{m}$ of the full group of fractional ideals, and a corresponding subgroup of principal ideals coprime to $\mathfrak{m}$. But you can check that this won't change the quotient - the class of $\mathfrak{m}$ is still represented by infinitely many *other* fractional ideals, and the remaining principal ideals still induce the same equivalences.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I understand: So we have firstly the natural inclusion $\mathcal{I}^{\mathfrak{p}}_K \subset \mathcal{I}^{(1)}_K$ (latter is the usual group of fractional ideals, let $ \mathcal{P}_K \subset  \mathcal{I}^{(1)}_K$ be the subgroup of principal fract ideals, (...which is by def identical with $  \mathcal{R}^{(1)}_K$ in the notes), and the hypothesis on surjectivity of unit map assures that $\mathcal{R}^{\mathfrak{p}}_K = \mathcal{I}^{\mathfrak{p}}_K \cap  \mathcal{P}_K$, right?

Comment: So we want to compare the quotients $C^{\mathfrak{p}}_K=\mathcal{I}^{\mathfrak{m}}_K /\mathcal{I}^{\mathfrak{p}}_K $ and $C_K=\mathcal{I}^{(1)}_K/\mathcal{P}_K$ (...latter is the "usual" ideal class group). By Minkowski's lattice theorem
even if  $\mathcal{I}^{(1)}_K$ is "huge" (for every prime ideal a free generator), $C_K$ is finite, so as you said every $\mathfrak{p}$ has of course infinitely many representatives in $\mathcal{I}^{(1)}_K$ which are all congruent modulo $\mathcal{P}_K$ to $\mathfrak{p}$, ie to spell it out there exist infinitely many fractial ideals $\mathfrak{f}$ such

Comment: that $\mathfrak{f}^{-1} \cdot \mathfrak{p} = (a_f)$ for certain $a_f \in K^{\times}$. BUT, in order to assume that $\mathfrak{p}$ has a representative in $C^{\mathfrak{p}}_K $ we need to assure that there exist a $\mathfrak{f} \in \mathcal{I}^{\mathfrak{p}}_K$ with $\mathfrak{f}^{-1} \cdot \mathfrak{p} = (a_f)$ where the principal ideal $(a_f)$ **lives in** $\mathcal{R}^{\mathfrak{p}}_K = \mathcal{I}^{\mathfrak{p}}_K \cap  \mathcal{P}_K$!.

Comment: And that's exactly what is still not clear to me how to archieve this condition. Do you see how to resolve this problem?