# Is the formal neighborhood of the diagonal a generalization of the Jet bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, differential-operators, d-modules

Let $f: X \to S$ be a morphism of locally ringed spaces and $\triangle: X \to X \times_S X$ the corresponding diagonal morphism with kernel sheaf $\mathcal{I} = \ker \triangle^{\flat}$.

> Definition: The $k$-th formal neighborhood of the diagonal of the
>   morphism $X \to S$ is the sheaf over $X$ given by the pullback:
>
> $$\triangle^{*}(\mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X} / \mathcal{I}^{k+1})$$

**Question** (vague): Is this the correct generalization of the jet bundle of a fibre bundle?

**Special case** (Less vague): Let $E \to X$ be a smooth vector bundle over a smooth manifold. Does the sheaf of sections of the jet bundle $\mathcal{J}^{k}(E)$ coincide with the sheaf given by the above procedure?

Comment: If $J^k = \Delta^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_{X\times X}/\mathcal{I}^{k+1})$, then $J^k$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-bimodules. The jet bundle $\mathcal{J}^k(E)$ is the same as $J^k\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} E$ which is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module using the left $\mathcal{O}_X$-action on $J^k$. Here it's important to take $\Delta^{-1}$ rather than $\Delta^*$ (inverse image of sheaves rather than pullback of $\mathcal{O}$-modules).

Comment: @PavelSafronov In the case where $E = M \times \mathbb{R}$ isn't this the same as the pullback of $\mathcal{O}$-modules?

Comment: Concerning the vague question: from the background I come from the jet bundle of a fiber bundle talks about sections of the bundle, while the construction you gave, if applied to a fiber bundle $X\to S$, seems to be about vertical (along the fibers) jets of functions. These might be related, but they do not seem to be a priori the same.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. If a vector bundle $E\rightarrow X$ is supposed to be a particular example of $X\rightarrow S$ (the appearance of $X$ threw me off), then clearly the two constructions give sheaves on different spaces (the first one on the target of the map and the second one on the source). What is the proposed relation between these?

Comment: @PavelSafronov I'm confused as well. I'm trying to connect the clearly related constructions of differential bi-modules (bi-modules supported on the diagonal with a full differential filtration) and jet bundles which are also related to this formal neighborhood of the diagonal stuff. In particular what is the sheaf charactrization of the jet bundle of a torsor.

Comment: I've asked something related to this not long ago: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/230373/unifying-justifying-the-various-definitions-for-differential-operators

Comment: I do not know too much about jet bundles, but I think http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20940/sheaves-of-principal-parts may be helpful.

Comment: I may be wrong but, thinking in terms of the tangent bundles only, if the OP wants a natural/canonical isomorphism, one would in particular like to have a natural isomorphism between the tangent bundle of the diagonal, and its normal bundle in the product. However, without additional structure, there is no canonical such isomorphism.